# Javascript Regex ignore case for specific capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

In PCRE this would be a valid expression

```
/^\!(foo|bar) ((?i)ab|cd|ef|gh)$/
```

But in JavaScript Regex this is not valid. Unfortunately I'm not aware what `(?i)` is called so I'm having some trouble googleing it. How would I translate this given example to be valid in JavaScript?

---

What I actually want to do:

find all lines which start with `!foo` or `!bar` followed by a space and end with `ab`, `cd`, `ef` or `gh`. The latter should be case insensitive.

```
!foo CD
!foo cD
!foo cd
```

would all be valid. While

!FOO cd
   !Foo cd

would be invalid

Answer (score 15):

The `(?i)` is the [`case-insensitive flag`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html): starting from the point inside your regex where it is placed it makes all the `character class` containing letter e.g. `[a-z]` to matches also `[A-Z]` (and viceversa). This works also for a single letter `a` (matches `a` and `A`) or sequence `ab` (matches `ab,Ab,aB,AB`).

So you can put it at the beginning of your regex `/(?i)regex/` (making it equivalent to the js `/regex/i`) or  you can use it together with its opposite `(?-i)` to  make only some section of the regex `case-insensitive`:

```
/^(?i)[a-z]{2}(?-i)[a-z]{2}/
```

The regex above matches 2 uppercase or lowercase chars plus 2 strictly lowercase chars.

> Matches ->   ROck, rOck, Rock
> Not Matches -> ROCK, roCk, rOcK

What about your PCRE regex?

```
/^\!(foo|bar) ((?i)ab|cd|ef|gh)$/
```

If you don't mind to match also a string starting with `!Foo,!FOo,!foO,!fOO,!BAR,!bar,...` you can put the flag outside, as this:

```
/^!(foo|bar) (ab|cd|ef|gh)$/i # you can also remove the escape from \! -> !
```

If you want instead the exact equivalent of the original PCRE regex (`/^!(foo|bar) ((?i)ab|cd|ef|gh)$/`) the equivalent **js** regex is the less readable:

```
/^!(foo|bar) ([Aa][Bb]|[Cc][Dd]|[Ee][Ff]|[Gg][Hh])$/
```

Comment: I tried putting your sample code in node and it's returning SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?i)[a-z]{2}(?-i)[a-z]{2}/: Invalid group

Comment: @zudduz thank you for letting me clarifying an ambiguous point. The regex you reported, ```/^(?i)[a-z]{2}(?-i)[a-z]{2}/``` is a [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) regex. It's cited in my answer just because the OP specifically asked for an explanation about the ```(?i)``` PCRE-operator . The equivalent for javascript is ```/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}/```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ECMAScript (JavaScript) documentation from here:

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

The `RegExp` is clearly defined there and it is not based on advanced Perl rules. So the `(?...)` syntax is not supported (see update below, that works in newer browsers).

One way to do what you want is to use the `[...]` for each character that need to be upper/lower case:

```
(?i)ab
```

becomes

```
[aA][bB]
```

It's a lot more typing, but I do not know of a better solution.

If the entire regex could be in any case, then you could use the flag:

```
/ab/i
```

But in your example, that means "foo" would also be accepted as "Foo" or "fOO".

---

#### Update

Newer versions of JavaScript do support the `(<flag>?...)` syntax.

> - DotAll is true if the RegExp object's [[OriginalFlags]] internal slot contains "s" and otherwise is false.
> - IgnoreCase is true if the RegExp object's [[OriginalFlags]] internal slot contains "i" and otherwise is false.
> - Multiline is true if the RegExp object's [[OriginalFlags]] internal slot contains "m" and otherwise is false.
> - Unicode is true if the RegExp object's [[OriginalFlags]] internal slot contains "u" and otherwise is false.

So Giuseppe Ricupero's answer applies for new browsers, Node, React, etc.